# Calling a method when the method name is contained in a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reflection

Let's say I have a page Test.aspx along with test.aspx.vb.

Test.aspx.vb contains a class name "TestClass". In that class I have method1(), method2() and method3()

I need to be able to call one of those methods, but I can't hard code it, the method to be executed comes from a string.

I can't do

```
Select Case StringContainingTheNameOfTheDesiredMethod
    Case "Method1" 
        Method1()
    Case "Method2"
       Method2()
end case
```

.

That I could find how to do with reflection ([I followed that example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx)). My problem is that those methods might need to interact with test.aspx, but when I use .invoke it seems to create a new thread or context and any reference to test.aspx becomes null (setting label1.text = "something" will generate a null reference, but a direct call of method1 (without invoke) will update label1.text just fine.

Is there any solution ? Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: What exactly can't you hard code?  The method string, or the method call itself?

Comment: The only solution I can find is to call a method that returns an object and use that object as a data source to interact with test.aspx, but since all the methods are already in test.aspx.vb, it would be simplier if I could simply interact with test.aspx within those methods.

Comment: I need to find a way to avoid that select case (or if statement) to call ? method. I have a string containing the name of the method that needs to be called, In a perfect world I would simply do something like excecuteMethod(StringWithMethodName)

Comment: The reflection method is the way to do it. You need to elaborate on what losing reference to test.aspx means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim xAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Dim xClass As Object = xAssembly.CreateInstance("Paradox.Intranet2.ManageUsers", False, BindingFlags.ExactBinding, Nothing, New Object() {}, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim xMethod As MethodInfo = xAssembly.GetType("Paradox.Intranet2.ManageUsers").GetMethod("TestCallFromString")

    Dim ret As Object = xMethod.Invoke(Me, New Object() {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of Test page to `Invoke` method (so you invoke it `on the object`). Sorry for C# code ;-)

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(TestPage).GetMethod(StringContainingTheNameOfTheDesiredMethod);
method.Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: Well, it helped me find the answer, but its not the exact answer ... so I upvoted your comment and answer.

Comment: You might want to update your question with the final solution to help others.